# OpenAPI3 json nested object complex query parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, openapi

I am trying to build complex query API.
Using open API to auto generate model classes and controller.
In open api 3 there is a support for complex object in query parameters.
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#schema-vs-content. I wish the doc had some examples..

My open Api:

```
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: filter
    content:
      application/json:      
        schema:
          schema:
           $ref: "#/components/schemas/ComplexFilter"
 components:
     schemas:
       ComplexFilter: 
           type: object
           properties:
             name:
               type: string
             lastname:
               type: string
             userName:
               type: string
```

Generated controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/users")
        @ResponseBody
        public List<User> search( @Parameter(name = "page") @RequestParam(value = "page") Integer page,
         @Parameter(name = "size") @RequestParam(value = "size") Integer size,
        @Parameter(name = "filter") ComplexFilter filter
            return service.filter(page,size,filter);
        }
```

The client application, in my case it's type script app, auto generated by OpenAPI Generator using generator version 6.1.0 looks like

```
public listUsers(page?: number, size?: number, filter?: ComplexFilter, options?: AxiosRequestConfig) {
        return UsersApiFp(this.configuration).listUsers(page, size, filter, options).then((request) => request(this.axios, this.basePath));
    }
```

Now is the problem: when I generate request it looks like

```
http://localhost:8085/api/v1/users?page=0&size=5&filter.name=test
```

but spring boot(server) expect query parameter without "filter." prefix

```
http://localhost:8085/api/v1/users?page=0&size=5&name=test
```

tried to set deepObject type in open api .. no luck

```
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: filter
    content:
      application/json:      
        schema:
          schema:
           $ref: "#/components/schemas/ComplexFilter"
          style: deepObject
          explode: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `content` keyword here, it's typically only used when the parameter value is a JSON string e.g. `filter={"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`.

Instead, add the `schema` directly to the parameter and use `style: form` + `explode: true` as the [serialization method](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query):

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: filter
    schema:
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/ComplexFilter"

    # Exploded form is the default serialization method for query params,
    # so these keywords can be omitted
    style: form
    explode: true
```

Comment: this is not true style: form + explode: true used only with primitives https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/

Comment: These keywords are used with objects and arrays too. Check the examples in the table in the "Query parameters" section.